Is the theory of two different structures always incomplete?
Let $L$ be a signature, and let $M$ and $N$ be two distinct $L$-structures which are not elementarily equivalent. Is the theory of the unordered pair $Th(\{M,N\})$ always incomplete? I apologize if this question is too basic.
